# cannot load redcapAPI package

Tags: r, redcap

I have been using redcapAPI package for sometime now to manage my dataset in REDCap. A few days ago, it started presenting some persistent error below

> library(redcapAPI)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘redcapAPI’:
>    object ‘[.labelled’ is not exported by 'namespace:Hmisc'

I have to re-install it, but the erroe keeps on showing whenever I want to use.
I do not understand how I go myself here, anyone kindly help.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall `Hmisc` also? What's your OS?

Comment: My OS is windows, yes I tried re-installing Hmisc, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

After a very long struggle, I got a solution to this. The problem was with the version of Hmisc that I was using. Previously, I was using version 4.0.3 and when I update my packages, a new version of Hmisc version 4.1.1 came along which was conflicting with redcapAPI. So, I locally installed an older version of Hmisc and everything was running smooth.

Comment: If this is still occurring with the current version of Hmisc, check out https://github.com/nutterb/redcapAPI/issues/158.  I  think @Benjamin addressed this.